# Converting a FeatureCollection to ImageCollection in Goolge Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, convert, ndvi, image, feature-collection

I created a Feature Collection of Ndvi (mean, min, max) from Image Collection. Now i want to convert FeatureCollection in ImageCollection in order to have a three bands (mean,min,max).How can help me?

```
var NDVI_POST= ee.ImageCollection(ETM_L7.merge(OLI_L8));
print(NDVI_POST)
var reducers=  ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
  sharedInputs: true
});
var ndvi = NDVI_POST.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('NDVI').reduceRegions({
    collection: fire_2007, 
    reducer: reducers,
    scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
     return f.set('imageId', image.id());
    });
}).flatten();
```

Comment: What is the reason that you convert this to feature collection at the first place?

Comment: Because I have to create training dataset (the input data as bands not properties) for SupervisedClassification.

Comment: Your code provide a single min,max, and mean value for each image in the image collection. It is just a value for whole the image. While, there are some functions like "mean", "min", and "max" that can directly apply on the image collection and provide you a mean image.

Comment: @hamikelvin i know but i want an ImageCollection not single Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Next time, please link to your script, or confirm that the code you have in your question can run without needing anything else (like `fire_2007`)

Anyway, here's how you would convert your Feature Collection to an Image Collection. The trick is this code:

```
  var properties = ["max", "mean", "min"]
  var image = ee.Image.constant(feature.toDictionary(properties).values())
```

It constructs an image from the chosen properties of a Feature.
If you map this over the Feature Collection you can convert your entire Feature Collection.

Here's my entire script with some extra stuff added:

```
var ndvi = NDVI_POST.map(function(image) {
  return image.select('NDVI').reduceRegions({
    collection: fire_2007, 
    reducer: reducers,
    scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
     return f.set('system:time_start', image.get("system:time_start"));
    });
}).flatten();

var ndvi_images = ndvi.map(function(feature){
  var date = feature.get("system:time_start")
  var properties = ["max", "mean", "min"]
  var image = ee.Image.constant(feature.toDictionary(properties).values())
  var renamed = image.rename(properties)
  return renamed.set("system:time_start", date)
})
```

[Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9accad0226c411787b3ea7845fb459cc)

Comment: thanks a lot it work!!

Comment: If i want computing NDVI mean, min, max of each image from ImageCollection directly. How i can do?

Comment: You can't really do that. I would say that your script right now is quite close to the normal workflow for this kind of task. Also, if my answer solved your question, I would appreciate it if you mark it as accepted :)